# Provision AWS Account Programmatically?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am trying to see if anyone knows if it is possible to provision an AWS account straight from   code? I have looked at the SDK and API reference but I am not seeing anything. It would be something similar to the way http://qwiklab.com/ provisions a new account for a user for training purposes.

Comment: I have done this in the past, can you give me an idea of your exact use case and how many accounts are you trying to provision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new AWS acount requires voice verification. AWS actually calls you to confirm. What you can do is create AWS IAM users and allocate very specific permissions within your Amazon VPC for these users. For example you can say users in group "A" can only launch AMIs tagged as "development" and only in a specific subnet. You can be somewhat granular in the permissions you allocate to IAM users/groups. Here is a list of actions you can specify for EC2 resources:

```
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources.html
```

Here is some general guidance on setting up control within your VPC:

```
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_IAM.html
```

The examples there can potentially serve as a good starting point for what you are trying to accomplish.